# V5 syntax error when using IN_RANGE in Cognos

Tags: cognos

I get the following error when trying to use IN_RANGE function in Cognos 10. any ideas why this is?

```
V5 syntax error found in expression "[Appointment Date] IN_RANGE", invalid token "" found after "[Appointment Date] IN_RANG".
```

The detail error:

> === JAVA STACK TRACE === XQE-V5-0011 V5 syntax error found in expression "[Appointment Date] IN_RANGE", invalid token "" found after
>   "[Appointment Date] IN_RANG". at
>   com.cognos.xqe.ast.v5Exp.V5ExpressionProcessor.processWithV5ExpressionParser(V5ExpressionProcessor.java:252)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.ast.v5Exp.V5ExpressionProcessor.process(V5ExpressionProcessor.java:125)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.transformation.v5.binding.ConvertV5ExpressionToBinary.apply(ConvertV5ExpressionToBinary.java:120)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QTETransformationEngine.applyTransformation(QTETransformationEngine.java:1225)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QTETransformationEngine.applyApplicableTransformation(QTETransformationEngine.java:1143)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QTETransformationEngine.applyIndexedTransformations(QTETransformationEngine.java:633)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QTETransformationEngine.transformationIteration(QTETransformationEngine.java:568)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QTETransformationEngine.applyTransformations(QTETransformationEngine.java:370)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.planner.QueryPlanner.plan(QueryPlanner.java:328)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.planner.QueryPlanner.planQuery(QueryPlanner.java:389)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.planner.QueryPlanner.planQuery(QueryPlanner.java:374)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QueryEngine.prepareRequest(QueryEngine.java:639)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QueryEngine.fetchRSAPIDatasets(QueryEngine.java:469)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.query.engine.QueryEngine.executeRequest(QueryEngine.java:421)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.bibushandler.ExecuteRequestAdapter.executeRequest(ExecuteRequestAdapter.java:112)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.cubingservices.V5QueryHandler.executeRequestInSequence(V5QueryHandler.java:622)
>   at
>   com.cognos.xqe.cubingservices.V5QueryHandler.execute(V5QueryHandler.java:463)
>   at
>   com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.v5.V5ProviderFacade.execute(V5ProviderFacade.java:109)
>   at
>   com.cognos.cubics.providers.cubingservices.CSStatement.execute(CSStatement.java:156)
>   at
>   com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.v5.V5RequestHandler.handleRequest(V5RequestHandler.java:59)
>   at
>   com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.comms.Servlet.processMessage(Servlet.java:128)
>   at
>   com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.comms.ComWorker.processQueryInputMsg(ComWorker.java:347)
>   at
>   com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.comms.ComWorker.processInput(ComWorker.java:252)
>   at com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.comms.ComWorker.call(ComWorker.java:162)
>   at com.ibm.cubeservices.mdx.comms.ComWorker.call(ComWorker.java:64) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314) at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:738) === END OF JAVA STACK TRACE
>   === RSV-SRV-0042 Trace back:RSReportService.cpp(752): XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSReportService::process()RSReportServiceMethod.cpp(263):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSReportServiceMethod::process():
>   asynchRunSpecification_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(808):
>   XQEException:
>   RSASyncExecutionThread::checkExceptionRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(260):
>   XQEException: CCL_CAUGHT: RSASyncExecutionThread::runImpl():
>   asynchRunSpecification_RequestRSASyncExecutionThread.cpp(864):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW: RSASyncExecutionThread::processCommand():
>   asynchRunSpecification_RequestExecution/RSRenderExecution.cpp(670):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSRenderExecution::executeAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(291):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSLayoutAssembly.cpp(79):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSLayoutAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSReportPagesAssembly.cpp(179):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSReportPagesAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSPageAssembly.cpp(303):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSPageAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableRowAssembly.cpp(177):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableRowAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(308):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchAssemblyAssembly/RSTableCellAssembly.cpp(137):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSTableCellAssembly::assembleAssembly/RSDocAssemblyDispatch.cpp(358):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSDocAssemblyDispatch::dispatchChildrenAssemblyForwardAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(662):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSAssembly::createListIteratorAssembly/RSAssembly.cpp(717):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSAssembly::createListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1055): XQEException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::getListIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1131):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::getResultSetIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1295): XQEException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: RSQueryMgr::createIteratorRSQueryMgr.cpp(1569):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgr::executeRsapiCommandRSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl.cpp(168):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   RSQueryMgrExecutionHandlerImpl::execute()QFSSession.cpp(1166):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1164): XQEException:
>   CCL_CAUGHT: QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSSession.cpp(1125):
>   XQEException: CCL_RETHROW:
>   QFSSession::ProcessDoRequest()QFSConnection.cpp(753): XQEException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: QFSConnection::ExecuteQFSQuery.cpp(135): XQEException:
>   CCL_RETHROW: QFSQuery::Execute v2XQEConnector.cpp(266): XQEException:
>   CCL_THROW: XQEConnector::send

Comment: Please post the data item or filter expression in full from your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out where the issue is. The datatype (currently being a date field) is not actually a date field so a simple CAST function did the quick fix. For a long term solution the datatype must be changed either in Framework Manager or Data Manager.

```
e.g. CAST([DATE] AS DATE)
```

Thanks,
Zak

Comment: The long term solution is to fix it in the database. Framework Manager and Data Manager just reflect what is in the database. Saving data data as character data is a very bad thing to do.